# How to swap between two resources in terraform

Tags: terraform

By mistake I imported the id of resource1 to the address of resource2 and vice versa.
How can I swap between them?

For example: I have two aws instances but the id of the first instance was imported to the second instance's resource address and the id of the second instance was imported to the first.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following bash script to swap between the resources:

```
export SECOND_RESOURCE_ID="i-222"

export FIRST_RESOURCE="aws_instance.first-instance"
export SECOND_RESOURCE="aws_instance.second-instance"

terraform state rm ${FIRST_RESOURCE} 
terraform state mv ${SECOND_RESOURCE} ${FIRST_RESOURCE} 
terraform import ${SECOND_RESOURCE} ${SECOND_RESOURCE_ID}
```

Comment: You can avoid the `rm` and `import` by moving the "first resource" to some separate address that doesn't really exist and then moving it back afterwards, although of course that comes with the risk that someone might run `terraform apply` in the middle of your script's execution and see a plan to destroy that object. But if you can prevent others from running Terraform while the script is running, `mv` is a more general solution because not all resource types can reliably `terraform import` and reproduce what was originally saved.

Comment: @MarkoE I haven't used the `move` block before. But from reading the docs, I believe that if I have made a mistake in this block I am in the same place and need a solution in order to swap between the resources

Comment: @MartinAtkins Your point is an important one. I basically want an atomic cli comand `terraform state swap ${SECOND_RESOURCE} ${FIRST_RESOURCE}`